# Why did Elijah run from Jezebel

Tags: 1-kings, elijah, jezebel

Edited to make more clearer.

In 1 Kings 19, Elijah runs from Jezebel after being threatened by her. I have two questions in relation to this.

- Would she have carried out that threat on a popular prophet?
- Why go to the furthest place possible (Mt Horeb) Why not go to Judah where he was from to be protected by the King of Judah?

Comment: Hi Alderney, welcome. To me this question needs more focus (hence the close vote). You mention "two questions" but you're asking four. Again, sharing based on my exp, when one has more than one question about a specific passage, the best is to reference the passage and ask them separately. For instances, you could have one with the title "Would Ahab and Jezebel kill a man like Elijah?". When you write the title often appears some similar questions. That saves up time searching to see if such question exists (and duplicates are not highly encouraged).

Answer (score 0):

Would she have carried out that threat on a popular prophet?

Definitely yes. Jezebel was an evil person.

> 1 Kings 19:1 Now Ahab told Jezebel everything Elijah had done and how he had killed all the prophets with the sword. 2So Jezebel sent a messenger to Elijah to say, “May the gods deal with me, be it ever so severely, if by this time tomorrow I do not make your life like that of one of them.”

Ahab killed a whole bunch of prophets already. What's one more? The threat was so real that

> 3 Elijah was afraid a and ran for his life.

Later Jezebel plotted to kill an innocent man Naboth in 1 Kings 21.

Why go to the furthest place possible (Mt Horeb) Why not go to Judah where he was from to be protected by the King of Judah?

At that time, Elizah did not trust the King of Judah. Israel and Judah had a good diplomatic relationship.
Later, in 1 Kings 22

> 2 But in the third year Jehoshaphat king of Judah went down to see the king of Israel.
> 3The king of Israel had said to his officials, “Don’t you know that Ramoth Gilead belongs to us and yet we are doing nothing to retake it from the king of Aram?”
>
> 4So he asked Jehoshaphat, “Will you go with me to fight against Ramoth Gilead?”
>
> Jehoshaphat replied to the king of Israel, “**I am as you are**, my people as your people, my horses as your horses.”